# Cannot add project after using tf destroy in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

It keeps showing the error:

> TF10175: The team project folder XXXX does not exists.

I'm sure that I have enough permission.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Has the new project the same name as the old one?